# Прыгают тултипы

Tags: css3, bootstrap

При наведении на элемент появляется тултип, но в момент наведения видно, как он поднимается снизу, т.е. невооруженным глазом виден его прыжок.

как это исправить?

Comment: Приведите пример кода. Может анимация в `css` добавлена?

Comment: http://joxi.ru/KAxjVO3h4wZXGm - разметка
http://joxi.ru/GrqyzoWFNb4d9r - начало кода
http://joxi.ru/VrwM3ORFKg73V2- продолжение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите аттрибут `tooltip-animation-class="fade"`

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!)